# How can I make colorbox to open in full when clicking on an image?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Right now the default behavior of colorbox is to move to the next image, when an image is clicked. How can I make colorbox open a new page with that image in full instead?

Thanks!

Comment: does the answer not work for you/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the greatest functionality, but you can hook into the cbox_complete event to define a handler which will unbind the current click handler and wrap the image in a link to itself:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mvfk/8/)

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    var $photo = $('.cboxPhoto').unbind("click");
    var src = $photo.attr('src');
    $photo.wrap('<a href="' + src + '" />');
});
```

Comment: Sorry my man, I was out of the country for a while. This works great :D